# PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'Caucasian\\m.077ytv\\34-FaceId-0_align.jpg' -> 'data\\Caucasian\\34-FaceId-0_align.jpg'

Tags: python, windows, file-permissions

Please I need help. I have buptbalanced faces and I am trying to move the image files in the different folders of the caucasian faces into a single folder. It worked fine in moving the other races (african, indian, asian) but I am getting this error for caucasian. running the code different times shows the error at different points. I am using jupyter notebook and have virtual env GPU here is my code

```
import os

CAU_PATH = os.path.join('data', 'Caucasian')

for directory in os.listdir('Caucasian'):
    for file in os.listdir(os.path.join('Caucasian', directory)):
        EX_PATH = os.path.join('Caucasian', directory, file)
        NEW_PATH = os.path.join(CAU_PATH, file)
        os.replace(EX_PATH, NEW_PATH)
```

Comment: This isn't a TensorFlow question.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I am learning deep learning with tensorflow and keras. how can I solve the problem please?

Comment: This is a Windows directory/file permissions issue.